# C# automatic logon to asp.net web site - not getting session id

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm creating C# application for automatic login to the asp.net web site and inserting data to the database. I've created simple asp.net app with login form and form for inserting data.

After an user log in, session is created with:

```
Session["user_id"] = ourDataTable.Rows[0].Field<int>(0).ToString();
```

I have checked all this in firefox and everything is working. First cookie is created after login (this is the only cookie):

```
**ASP.NET_SessionId**:"pa02cjwxbttuahgy4yag5p42"
```

POST request have these paarameters:

```
__VIEWSTATE /wEPDwULLTIwOTg3Njg1NzEPZBYCAgMPZBYCAg8PPCsAEQEMFCsAAGQYAQUJR3JpZFZpZXcxD2dksGuyiof5KI1ZjCROJlySTTsKbZBN7nTTn+F6hDT/b6k=
tbUserName  testuser
tbPassword  tespassword
cmdLogIn    Log+In
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR    6ED0046F
__EVENTVALIDATION   /wEdAAQePgQDMR/AUHZLXDXQQd7GhI6Xi65hwcQ8/QoQCF8JIahXufbhIqPmwKf992GTkd1uO09HhNZCp8pktuS4KS9M7pTIzwnXrobBxeBO8phx+9mT+uRYJ9Acvt0eC7tXcV8=
```

But I'm not able to login in from C#.

I've extracted VIEWSTATE, VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and EVENTVALIDATION (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e02f731-bc2e-4d85-835c-ac885d2e4ee5/webrequest-post?forum=csharplanguage).

**I POST all parameters but not getting ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. I'm not getting any cookies.** Here is my code (part for login, I have procedures for extracting parameters):

```
        // first, request the login form to get the viewstate value 
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57478/LoginForm.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        // extract the VIEWSTATE, VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and EVENTVALIDATION values and build out POST data 
        string viewState = ExtractViewState(responseData);

        string viewStateGenerator = ExtractViewStateGenerator(responseData);

        string eventValidation = ExtractEventValidation(responseData);

        string postData = "__VIEWSTATE=" + viewState +
            "&tbUserName=testuser" +
            "&tbPassword=tespassword" +
            "&cmdLogIn=Log+In" +
            "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=" + viewStateGenerator +
            "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + eventValidation;

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        // now post to the login form
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57478/LoginForm.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postData));
        MessageBox.Show(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postData));
        requestWriter.Close();

        // we don't need the contents of the response, just the cookie it issues
        webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
        MessageBox.Show(webRequest.GetResponse().Headers.ToString());
        // now we can send out cookie along with a request for the protected page
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57478/RedirectForm.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        // and read the response
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(responseData);
```

Last MessageBox is showing Logon page.

What is wrong?

Best regards,

Brane.

Comment: What is the http result code of the first request and the second? BTW, you don't need to add viewstate and eventvalidation. That could even be your problem since hash of viewstate is validated.

Comment: From C# I'm not sure how to get response code. From firefox I can see that when I first open logon page I'm getting code 200, and after I log in I got code 302. Regarding viewstate and eventvalidation, I've  used code from link that I've posted. Without vievstate (or with wrong value) I'm getting an error in event viewer.

Comment: This may be of some help https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/authenticating-to-asp-net-membership-provider-programmatically/

Comment: I'll check this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally got it working.

Relevant parts that I've added are:

```
        NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("__VIEWSTATE", viewState);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("tbUserName", "testuser");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("tbPassword", "testpassword");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("cmdLogIn", "Log In");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", viewStateGenerator);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation);

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outgoingQueryString.ToString());
```

Instead of:

```
    string postData = "__VIEWSTATE=" + viewState +
        "&tbUserName=testuser" +
        "&tbPassword=tespassword" +
        "&cmdLogIn=Log+In" +
        "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=" + viewStateGenerator +
        "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + eventValidation;
```

And at the end (replaced all from "// write the form values into the request message"):

```
        // write the form values into the request message
        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        // get the contents of the response (after logon page is redirected)
        responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
```

So, here is final working code:

```
        // first, request the login form to get the viewstate value
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57478/LoginForm.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        // extract the VIEWSTATE, VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and EVENTVALIDATION values and build out POST data 
        string viewState = ExtractViewState(responseData);

        string viewStateGenerator = ExtractViewStateGenerator(responseData);

        string eventValidation = ExtractEventValidation(responseData);

        NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("__VIEWSTATE", viewState);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("tbUserName", "testuser");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("tbPassword", "testpassword");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("cmdLogIn", "Log In");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", viewStateGenerator);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation);

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outgoingQueryString.ToString());

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        // now post to the login form
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57478/LoginForm.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        // write the form values into the request message
        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        // get the contents of the response (after logon page is redirected)
        responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
```

Comment: Any chance you can post your code for ExtractViewState, ExtractViewStateGenerator

Comment: @Aarif
private string ExtractViewState(string s)
{
 string viewStateNameDelimiter = "__VIEWSTATE";
 string valueDelimiter = "value=\"";

int viewStateNamePosition = s.IndexOf(viewStateNameDelimiter);
int viewStateValuePosition = s.IndexOf(valueDelimiter, viewStateNamePosition);
int viewStateStartPosition = viewStateValuePosition + valueDelimiter.Length;
int viewStateEndPosition = s.IndexOf("\"", viewStateStartPosition);

return s.Substring(viewStateStartPosition, viewStateEndPosition - viewStateStartPosition);
}

Comment: @Aarif
private string ExtractViewStateGenerator(string s)
{
string viewStateGeneratorNameDelimiter = "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR";
string valueDelimiter = "value=\"";
int viewStateGeneratorNamePosition = s.IndexOf(viewStateGeneratorNameDelimiter);
int viewStateGeneratorValuePosition = s.IndexOf(valueDelimiter, viewStateGeneratorNamePosition);
int viewStateGeneratorStartPosition = viewStateGeneratorValuePosition + valueDelimiter.Length;
int viewStateGeneratorEndPosition = s.IndexOf("\"", viewStateGeneratorStartPosition);

Comment: @Aarif (last two lines from proc for previous comment)
return s.Substring(viewStateGeneratorStartPosition, viewStateGeneratorEndPosition - viewStateGeneratorStartPosition);
}

Comment: This response was an absolute life-saver for me. The extract methods you posted in the and the code you provided for the answer was exactly what I needed to get my app working with the viewstate form post. Thank you!